# Function that checks that list one is the beginning of list 2

Tags: list, sml, tail, head, smlnj

I'm trying to create a function that takes two lists and checks whether the first list is the start of the second list. I have the following pseudo code:

- an empty list starts a list
- a list does not start an empty list
- a list starts a second list if the they have the same head and tail of the second list

Could someone please explain a good way to tackle this problem?

for the first pseudocode statement I thought of doing something like:

```
fun starts [] l2 = false |
    starts l1 [] = false |
    starts l1 l2 = if ((hd(l1) = (hd(l2) andalso (tl(l1) = (tl(l2)) then true
```

I'm not entirely sure whether this would work as what if the second lists tail is longer than the first lists tail? would an error occur?

If someone could help explain or even find a solution, that would be great!

---

EDIT:

Found a way of doing it, I don't think I was too far off.

```
Fun start [] l2 = true |
start l1 [] = false |
start l1 l2 = if (hd(l1)) = (hd(l2)) then (start (tl(l1)) (tl(l2))) else false;
```

Comment: Your approach is ok. For the last line `((hd(l1) = (hd(l2) andalso (tl(l1) = (tl(l2))` you would like to have a recursive call to continue the evaluation for the subsequent elements untill you get to the pattern `[] l2`

Comment: Also, there is no need to use an if statement. `((hd(l1) = (hd(l2) andalso (tl(l1) = (tl(l2))` is equivalent to `if ((hd(l1) = (hd(l2) andalso (tl(l1) = (tl(l2)) then true else false`. So write `if ((hd(l1) = (hd(l2) andalso (tl(l1) = (tl(l2)) then true ` and now figure a way to continue the recursive call from that point onwards. Also the first line should be true not false

Comment: oops.. I mean to say: so write `((hd(l1) = (hd(l2) andalso (tl(l1) = (tl(l2))` and now figure a way to continue the recursive call from that point onwards. Another hint: you replace  (tl(l1) = (tl(l2) with something else as you need to compare one element at a time.

Comment: I eventually managed to get it. I'll update the code. Thanks for the help! In the end I still used an if statement, but might give it a go trying without one.

Comment: I'm now trying to find out whether one list contains items of another list. Would you be able to suggest a good way to go about this?

Comment: Your current function is already checking this. What do you mean?

Comment: Sorry I haven't been clear enough, but it doesn't matter anymore, I managed to solve that issue. But thanks for your help anyway :)

Answer (score 2):

With pattern matching, but without conditionals:

```
fun start [] l2 = true 
  | start l1 [] = false 
  | start (x::xs) (y::ys) = x = y andalso start xs ys
```

Comment: Would you mind looking at my most recent question please? It's about removing a list from another list. It makes more sense in my post. If you could, that would be great! Thanks.